# pywinauto - how to right-click in systemtray, select an item then subitem

Tags: python, python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto

I have an application in the hidden part of the systray in Windows 10. I am trying to connect to the application, right-click on it, and then select something like "About". I understand that once I have the target application, I need to connect to the application, which I do in line 25 of the code, but I cannot get further from there.

This is the code I have so far:

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
systemTray = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
systemTray.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").click_input(button="left")
#systemTray.print_control_identifiers()
time.sleep(0.25)

list_box = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win = list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)

# List all the icons in the systray
for notification_area in list_box_win.children():
    for app_in_tray in notification_area.children():
        print(str(app_in_tray))

target_app = list_box_win.child_window(title="TrayStatus Pro Trial 4.6\r\nCaps Lock: Off")
target_app.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)
target_app.click_input(button="right")
target_app.target_app.print_control_identifiers()
target_app.dump_tree()

sysapp = Application().connect(path='TrayStatus.exe')
sysapp.menu_select('About') #This part fails
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application()` class represents the application and sometime it fails to identify the window. Having said that, you have not mentioned the backend of the application at the beginning you have used `UIA` backend so figure out for the line `sysapp = Application().connect(path='TrayStatus.exe')` as well and add, Also adding `timeout=10` parameter to the `connect()` works many times.

Still if the above option doesn't not work for you then try using `Desktop` class.
again you can mention backend of your choice and compatibility, there is no such way to identify backend of application.

```
window2 = Desktop(backend="win32").window(title='title of the rayStatus.exe window')
```

you will need to import  -

`from pywinauto import Desktop`.

Finally you can print the titile of windows using

```
list_window = Desktop().windows()
for window in list_window:
    window.window_texts()  # this should print the all open window names on desktop
```